# How to navigate Tree View in Internet Explorer using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've got another one for all you Selenium Gurus!

In Chrome and Firefox this xPath works perfectly but IE gives me an error.

**//*[contains(text(), 'Mercedes Benz')]**

I'm navigating a native tree view object to the third child item under the first parent (Cars)

I've also tried contatins partialtext().

Any insights?

***CARS:***
 - Audi
 - BMW
 - Mercedes Benz
 - Rolls Royce
***MOTORCYCLES:***
 - Bugati
 - Harley Davidson
 - Triumph

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you post/link the actual source?

Comment: webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Mercedez Benz')]")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my internet explorer driver to the latest version and it solved the problem.  Thanks everyone!